# diff для стандартов C++

Tags: c++11, c++14, c++17, стандарт, c++20

Вдруг понял, что я совсем не знаю С++20. Но изучать С++ с нуля чтобы увидеть отличия, времени нет.

Нет ли где-то изложения **различий** стандартов С++? Желательно еще с С++11 - только не просто название изменившихся или добавленных "фич", а так чтоб с описанрием, пусть и кратким?

Или кто-то может привести это прямо в ответе?

C++11 -> C++14 -> C++17 -> C++20

Нет, вернее по важности так:

C++20 -> C++17 -> C++14 -> C++11

Comment: Помните о главном, программы пишутся *для других программистов*. Чем большее их число будет легко воспринимать ваш код, тем лучше.

Comment: я бы сказал не программы, а код программ, плохо напишешь, полезешь через год и не поймешь сам зачем так делал

Comment: [11 -> 14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1319r0.html), [14 -> 17](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html), [17 -> 20](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2131r0.html).

Comment: @wololo Перенесите свой комментарий в ответ, хорошо?

Answer (score 3):

Можно посмотреть много где. Самое точное и правильное место -- стандарт, конечно (например, http://eel.is/c++draft/#diff). Но более удобно и читабельно на cppreference, заодно есть информация о поддержке компиляторами:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/14 -- 14!

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/17 -- 17!

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20 -- 20!